# Use include filter in custom post type by custom post field

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, ionic3

I am trying to do the following:

```
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?include=17,15
```

That HTTP call return only post with `id=17` and `id=15`.

I have a custom post type(activity) with a custom post field(order_id) and I want to retrieve only the activities with specific `order_id`. For example

```
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/activities-api?order_id=2
```

That HTTP call return the activity with the `order_id=2`. 
How can I use the include filter with custom post type and custom post field?

`example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/activities-api?order_id=2,4,5` For example, get in one HTTP call the activities with `id 2,4,5`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show the code that you are using?

Comment: I only want to get in one http call 3 activities(2,4,5 for example) using WP Rest API.